# Radar maths I and Q components

Tags: signal, waveform, radar

I have just started work with radars. I read that incoming signal in case of Doppler radar is frequency shifted. On adding it to original signal we get Doppler shift. But we don't do it directly. First we make I component (by mixing incoming signal with LO signal) then Q signal by mixing original signal with phase shifted LO then do I + jQ. This I understand is to determine the direction of motion either towards or away from Radar. I am attaching excerpt from book. Can anyone please explain how this one signal in each waveform becomes zero?

[image: From Micro Doppler Effect in Radar by Victor C. Chen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the value of f<sub>D</sub> can be positive or negative. The sign of f<sub>D</sub> has no effect on the I signal (cos(x) = cos(-x)), but it reverses the sign of the Q signal (sin(x) = -sin(-x)).

The 90° phase shifter delays the Q signal — its output is Q<sup>90</sup>(t) = -sin(2πf<sub>D</sub>t - π/2) = cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) when f<sub>D</sub> is positive, but it becomes
-cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) when f<sub>D</sub> is negative.

Therefore, when f<sub>D</sub> is positive, the upper adder outputs cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) - cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) = 0, but when f<sub>D</sub> is negative, it outputs cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) - (-cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t)) = 2 cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t).

Similarly, when f<sub>D</sub> is positive, the lower adder outputs cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) + cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) = 2 cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t), but when f<sub>D</sub> is negative, it outputs cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t) + (-cos(2πf<sub>D</sub>t)) = 0.

Comment: If we look like this -sin(2*pi*fd*t- pi/2)=sin(pi/2 - 2*pi*fd*t). And sin(pi/2-a) equals cosa no matter what sign of a is. (Here a would be 2*pi*fd*t). So in either case output is same. I am thinking like this. Any comments?

Comment: You're still ignoring the fact that the sign of the Q signal changes with the sign of \$f_D\$, before you apply the processing shown in the diagram.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This was bugging me a lot. Now got hold of it.